# Need help to resolve modal popup issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing modal popup into my application. I am doing modal popup for my login form.
I took the plugin from "http://deseloper.org/read/2009/10/jquery-simple-modal-window". 
This will take entire login form to popup, but i want only certain div's in the form. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suggest you look at the [jQuery UI modal.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-form.html)

There you can load parts of current page, parts of another page and only show fragments you get at using the usual selectors